# Index of element with given property based on the rest of the sequence

Tags: r, indexing

Hey I have following vector of 0's and 1's:

```
x = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
```

I want to find an index of the first element from sequence of 1's which length exceeds the length of every subsequent string of 0's. So in my example the solution should be "10", because three last elements of x are: `1, 1, 0` so length of sequence 1, 1 is greater than length of any subsequent string of 0's. How can I do that in R?

Comment: Could there be multiple sequences of ones that fulfill the criteria?

Comment: Rather not, we are looking for the first sequence of 1's with this property (going from the left) so if we have sequence `1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0` then the solution should be index one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
which.max(with(rle(x), rep(values * (lengths > c(tail(lengths, - 1), 0)), lengths)))
```

The results for different x values:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)

[1] 10

x <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)

[1] 5

x <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)

[1] 1
```

However, this assumes that there is at least one such sequence.

For cases with no sequence fulfilling the criteria:

```
ind <- with(rle(x), rep(values * (lengths > c(tail(lengths, - 1), NA)), lengths))
if(length(which(ind == 1)) == 0) NA else min(which(ind == 1))
```